# Apple Internal Hard Drive Error

Tags: hard-drive, imac, hardware, desktop, repair

So long story short, my iMac was working perfectly fine and I just decided to restart it because the fan was loud, it made a weird noise and now it keeps taking me back to either reinstall my macos, disk utility, and time machine.

I try clicking my Macintosh HD but it isn't even showing even after running first aid it says that "it has failed, is possible back up data on this volume". I also went on reinstall macos but does not show my Mac HD in there ... Any solutions ? [image]

Comment: start in safe mode and try to fix it from there with fschk

Comment: it also says your disk is 101% full ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have done that and said everything is ok but still brings me back to macOS utilities

Comment: d you remember how full was your disk before this

Comment: @Buscar웃 it was only 380gb used

Answer (score 1):

You really need to put this Mac in target disk mode and connect it to another Mac - or you can accomplish the same things buy installing a fresh copy of Mac OS on a USB external drive and booting that.

Once you're running normal Mac OS on another drive, you can run `SMART Utility` to see if your drive is having a hardware failure. If it is, time to replace it. If it's not, you should run a good drive repair utility like `DiskWarrior`. Unfortunately, while Apple's `Disk Utility` technically performs these functions, it's fairly useless at both.

Comment: I have a time machine back up but thats from 2017, if I were to load that would that delete all the existing files I currently had with the old ones?

Comment: Yes, and if you have a hardware drive problem, doing something like that would make the drive much worse, potentially killing it in the process. You need to see what the problem is first then go from there.